# CSS placing two divs next to another

Tags: css

I'm trying to build a template using divs.

A top div width 100%, no problem there.

Beneath that on the left and the right a small div both 200px
in between the main container consisting  of two of columns both 50% of what is left.

**My problem is these two colums get the size of 50% of the viewport, so the second column is placed under the main view.**

### HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="but">top 1234</div>
    <div class="but">top 5678</div>
    <div class="but">top 91011</div>
    <div class="but">top 121314</div>
</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="butsRight">
        <div class="butv">right1234</div>
        <div class="butv">right567</div>
        <div class="butv">right8910</div>
    </div>
    <div id="butsLeft">
        <div class="butv">left1234</div>
        <div class="butv">left5678</div>
        <div class="butv">left91011</div>
    </div>
    <div id="middleMain">
        <div id="middleMainL">
            <div id="middleMainLb">LEFT QQQQQ
                <br>CCCCC
                <br>hhhhhh</div>
            <div id="middleMainLm">
                <table width=100% height=100% border=2>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="middleMainLo">LEFT
                <p>eee</p>
                <p>fff</p>
                <p>ggg</p>
                <p>hhh</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--middleMainL -->
        <div id="middleMainR">
            <div id="middleMainRb">RIGHT QQQQQ
                <br>CCCCC
                <br>hhhhhh</div>
            <div id="middleMainRm">RIGHT
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>bbbb</p>
                <p>cccc</p>
                <p>dddd</p>
                <p>aaaa</p>
                <p>bbbb</p>
                <p>cccc</p>
            </div>
            <div id="middleMainRo">RIGHT
                <p>eee</p>
                <p>fff</p>
                <p>ggg</p>
                <p>hhh</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--middleMainR -->
    </div>
    <!-- middlemain -->
</div>
<!-- middle -->
```

### CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#top {
    margin-right: 80px;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#butsLeft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
#butsRight {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}
#middleMain {
    background-color: gray;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#middleMainL {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
#middleMainR {
    width:auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: brown;
}
#middleMainLb {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
#middleMainLm {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}
#middleMainLo {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
#middleMainRb {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
#middleMainRm {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: purple;
    text-align: center;
}
#middleMainRo {
    width: 100%;
    float: center;
    background-color: green;
    text-align: center;
}
div.but {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolut;
    display:inline-block;
}
div.butv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolut;
    height: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Do me a favour, you draw the layout in paint or something and then I will make it for you + explain it. I hate messy code like you have so I'm not going to touch it.

Comment: @casthegohst : mate...its too messed up....tidy up a bit and u'll have d answer den!! :)

Comment: sorry guys.. it is my first question here... and @ruddy not allowed to place pics yet. That's why I put it here [link] http://www.consult4.nl/even/plane.gif   hope this clesrs things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I had a little look at it and this is what I came up with. Please do look into it a little to understand the code. Its fairly straight forward.

### HTML:

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="right">Right Side Bar: Fixed width.</div>
<div id="left">Left Side Bar: Fixed width.</div>
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <div id="middleleft">Middle Left</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="middleright">Middle Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
#right, #left {
    width:200px;
    height: 500px;
    float:left;
    background:orange;
}
#right {
    float:right;
}
#content {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 500px;
}
#content > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
#middleleft {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: blue;
}
#middleright {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: green;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz352/1/)

Comment: thx a lot @Ruddy I will have a look at the #content > div part... I think that's what I was missing!

Comment: Np, thats the layout you are looking for so as I said mess around with it or even use it and you should be all good! If this did answer your question +1 and selecting it as the correct answer would be much appreciated. Anymore questions about this please let me know and I will try and help you.

Comment: since it is my first question and not been able to give others answers I´m not allowed to vote yet... verry happy with your answer though....

Comment: Glad your happy with it, you should be able to accept the answer tho. Tick on the side of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I did it, but this is what you want (maybe? 'cause I didn't really understood the question)

http://jsfiddle.net/KTd8T/1/

When you were doing your css, you were doing some .example when example was a div. If it's a div, put `#`, if it's a class put "."

Now you can work on this copy and just try to write clear code.

There is another point: you are doing a top, and middle content, but you don't have a bottom content. Maybe this is why it's not display like you want ?

Thanks for editing your post and try to be more explicite !